# Slowly scroll the content of a div on hover and stop on mouseoff

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Please take a look at this [website](http://www.prozign.com.php53-17.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/projects/)

I'm trying to implement two arrows on top and bottom of the gallery so when people mouse over the arrows, the content would scroll top and bottom respectively.

Here is the code I'm currently using that scrolls the content down when you hover over the bottom arrow. But there are two issues with it:

1. I want the scrolling to stop when the user mouses off
2. Hopefully do not display the arrow(s) if there is no more content left to scroll

   ```
   if ( $("body").hasClass('projects') ) {
       $("#jig1").height($(document).height() - 187);

       $("#scroll-to-bottom").hover(
           function () {
               $("#jig1").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
           },
           function () {

           }
       );
   }
   ```

Can anyone offer an improved solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the seccond question. 
Add the inner wrapper to the divs blocks
Html should look like this

```
<div id="jig1">
   <div id="jig1Inner">
     ... here put rest of the code
```

---

```
if ($("body").hasClass('projects')) 
{
    $("#jig1").height($(document).height() - 187);

    var watchScrollers = function()
    {
        var tmp = $("#jig1Inner").height() - $("#jig1").height();
        if (tmp == $("#jig1").scrollTop()) 
        {
            $("#scroll-to-bottom").css("visibility","hidden");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#scroll-to-bottom").css("visibility","visible");
        }
        if ($("#jig1").scrollTop() == 0) 
        {
            $("#scroll-to-top").css("visibility","hidden");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#scroll-to-top").css("visibility","visible");
        }
    }

    $("#scroll-to-bottom").unbind("hover").hover(function() {
        $("#jig1").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#jig1Inner").height() - $("#jig1").height()}, 10000);
    }, function() {
        $("#jig1").stop(); //stops the animation
        watchScrollers();
    });
    $("#scroll-to-top").unbind("hover").hover(function() {
        $("#jig1").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 10000);
    }, function() {
        $("#jig1").stop(); //stops the animation
        watchScrollers();
    });
    watchScrollers();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Infira for the full answer. I'm however using a third party plugin to create that gallery. The layout is defined in a [minified javascript file](http://www.prozign.com.php53-17.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/plugins/justified-image-grid/js/justified-image-grid-min.js) a little hard to inject that inner div. If your code requires that inner div, is it possible for me to wrap everything inside it when the page loads and then run you code and don't change the code on the third party plugin?

Comment: if you cand change the html then
do that 
After that code "$("#jig1").height($(document).height() - 187);"
pu this line of code 
$("#jig1").children().wrapAll('<div id="jig1Inner" />');

Comment: Thank you, I've [implemented](http://www.prozign.com.php53-17.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/projects/) your solution. Looks great.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#scroll-to-bottom").mouseover( function () {
   $("#jig1").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
});

$("#scroll-to-bottom").mouseout( function () {
   $("#jig1").stop()
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was great. I didn't know about stop(). Any suggestion on how to hide the arrow when I reach the end and display it again if user scrolls back up?